# Godot Centerpoint Offset causes inaccurate aiming with function look_at()

Tags: godot

I have a Problem concerning a 2D Tower Defense Game i am programming in Godot 4. I have Enemies which move on a 2d Path and Turrets which are using the look_at() function on the PathFollow2D.position of the Enemies. As you can see there is also a health bar which should be at a constant height above the players head. The Problem is that the further the Enemies move to right/down/up , the more inaccurate the turrets get, up to the point where they are completely missing the target when they are almost on the right of the screen. The Offset is tiny but enough to make the bullet miss. The interesting thing is that the health bar which should remain at a constant height above the head, also moves slightly when the Enemie is traveling. Both the "Enemie" and its Parent "banshee" are locatet in x=0 and y =0. This Problem is bothering me for 2 weeks now and it just makes no sense to me at all the look_at() function is literaly just having one argument which is the Position of banshee, thats why i didnt screenshot it. Its ridiculous to see the towers hitting on point at the beggining which is around x/y = 0, and completely miss the further they go away.

i tried almost everything and i cant even figure out where the problem might even come from i tested so many times and changed a lot of paramters but nothing seems to fix it the only thing i can do is too create a vector to compensate for the incaccuracy but thats not a real solution to the problem

Comment: About the health bar, the only thing that comes to mind is the `gui/common/snap_controls_to_pixels` option in project settings. And about the turrets, they shoot a projectile - which has some travel time - correct? There is plenty of literature on aiming at a moving target, you can try searching on this site, and on gamedev.stackexchange.com - if you want my take, see [Model path of bullet to hit future position of balloon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/201516/10408).